# adding an option to the android gallery like facebook or flickr

Tags: android, facebook, gallery, photo, flickr

I would like to add an option to the photo gallery like the facebook and flickr (tabs)

How is that done?

I can create an intent-filter that handles images but I want the photo's to appear in the gallery like the imaged of picasa, facebook and flickr.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android), and get the image URLs through the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api). Then you can load these images into an [Android GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to get the effect you want.